# How can I upgrade AWS SAM to a certain version?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm trying to upgrade SAM CLI, version 1.18.2 to 1.22.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. I used brew command:

```
~brew upgrade aws-sam-cli@1.22.0
```

but didn't work. Showed the next message:

```
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "aws-sam-cli@1.22".
```

Also I'm trying to find a downloadable to install a certain version.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1767

> For anyone in the future, use pip.
>
> pip3 install --user 'aws-sam-cli==1.12.0'